# Understand free command with top command

Tags: command-line, ram, memory-usage, memory-leak

I have a doubt.

I start ubuntu and run free command. I will get the total free space available. Let say it as 100MB.

Now I run a few applications.

So after some time, I again run the free command. Now it is 80MB..

The total used memory is 20MB. Is there a way to find which applications have used this 20 MB of memory. Can top command be of any help in this??

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not exactly familiar with how `top` formatting works, I can offer a few work-arounds.

**PS**

`ps` command is comes with procps package and is among standard utilities, that is readily available on your system. `-aux` switches will output processes for all users and programs on the system, while `--sort %mem` is used to sort output by % of memory used. 
In short: `ps -aux --sort %mem`.

**HTOP**

Htop is a variation of top, but with much nicer appearance and features (at least IMHO).
Pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> will allow you to sort output by whatever quality you want, again by memory, and again in percentage.

[image]

**Some considerations**:
As to why would the memory be eaten up this much, you may know that a closed program doesn't always mean its process was stopped - it may actually hang around and eat up your memory. Which is where you can user `htop` or `ps` to find that process's pid, and kill it with `kill` command or `htop` build-in kill function. Try playing with a process priority levels in System Monitor program (right click on the process and hover cursor over Changer Priority). Although this is more related to CPU usage, CPU uses memory to process each command and only simpler tasks are in the internal registers (if i remember correctly from  intro to computer science class).

Comment: Small additional note: `free` and `top` format output in KiB , which is powers of 2 (2^32 = 4,294,967,296 or 4.3 GiB), but `free -h` is human-readable in GB, which is closest round values ( 4GB in this case )

Answer (score 0):

Top displays the active processes, including the memory.

System monitor is the user friendly (GUI) way to memory usage analysis, provided the applications are still open.

Also, take a note that, once memory used in a session by a program, it may be still in a buffer until it's needed by another program. From the manual:

```
free displays the total amount of free and used physical and swap memory
in the system, as well as the buffers used by the kernel.
```

So if you close for example Firefox, that memory may be held in cache just in case you want to start Firefox again.